# Change a single parameter in URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to be able to create a link to the same route I'm on, **except for changes to some parameters**.

In my website, I decided to have a URL structured like this: `/list/:page(\d+)?/:filter?`. Now, in my component I have access to `match` (using `withRouter` HOC). In my situation it contains

```
{
  isExact: true
  params: {page: "3", filter: "duckbitt"}
  path: "/listing/:page(\d+)?/:filter?"
  url: "/listing/3/duckbitt"
}
```

This is very good, as I have both params and the path.
Now, this raises 2 questions:

1. Is there a react-router builtin solution for such a situation?
2. If not, is there a possible solution using `path-to-regexp`, or I should use naive search and replace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course a solution shows up right after posting the question.

```
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
// (...)
const toPath = pathToRegexp.compile(match.path);
const newPath = toPath({ ...match.params, page: 666 });
console.log(newPath); // "/listing/666/duckbitt"
```